# Apache 2 + virtual hosts on different folders

Tags: apache

I have a folder named **www** with my applications:
/www/app1_folder/
/www/app2_folder/
/www/app3_folder/

Also I have one external ip and domain name **www.example.org***.

If I refer my apps without virtual host settings It looks:
http://www.example.org/app1_folder/
http://www.example.org/app2_folder/
http://www.example.org/app3_folder/

But problem is my apps share a session environment.

I would like to save the approach of my apps referring (i.e **http://www.example.org/app1_folder/**, ...) without sharing of environment.

I hope it's possible with virtual host setting of apache.

**How can I make virtual hosts based on different names of folder (i.e. app1_folder, app2_folder, app2_folder)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A virtual host is defined by a domain name (foo.mysite.com) and a port (:80, ...).

You cannot create several virtual hosts by using the same domain name/port.